# entity field type with symfony 3

Tags: symfony

i m new in symfony 3.
i have to say that a ticket belong to one  category
. in the forma of Ticket creation 
the user will be able to choose one category . the realtion between the entity category and the entity ticket is **"OneToMany"** and the field category appear in the form but its type is class and not a simple attribute.
 How can i put a list of choice  related to an entity  which is a field type of form ?
Do i have to create a controller and a form type to get the propriate field ?
i'm really confused and running out of time. 
please give me your solutions if you had ever faced this problem. Thanks

Comment: Hi Ryhab, it is best that you post code that is giving you issues. While the question is specific, there is no code shown that other can assist you with in fixing. In your case, it seems you need to review the documentation on Forms from Symfony. http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html (General Guide). Entity Guide for forms choice selection: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: @AndrewNolan i have read that doc but i didn't find a solution to my problem.

Comment: As suggested by Andrew, you should provide code from your form and both entities Ticket and Category

Comment: Would at least need to see the your defined relationship between ticket and category before even taking a stab at providing an answer. I can type up a general answer that might fit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general answer where the relationship between a Country and a Territory is One to Many (Country having many Territories) and should match your Ticket / Category relationship. Since you are missing code to provide a better answer, this will have to do.

This is inside of a Form Type class called TerritoryType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Territory Name',
        ])
        ->add('abbrev', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Territory Abbreviation',
        ])
        ->add('belongingCountry', EntityType::class, [
            'class'         => 'AppBundle:Address\Country',
            'choice_label'  => 'name',
            'label'         => 'Country'
        ])
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
}
```

In this case belongingCountry is an entity of Country. All Country entities are displayed for selection based on the Country name. If you choose to use the forum builder inside of your controller, it will be something like this inside your controller method.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($territory)
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('abbrev', TextType::class)
        ->add('belongingCountry', EntityType::class , [
             class'         => 'AppBundle:Address\Country',
            'choice_label'  => 'name',
            'label'         => 'Country'
            ])
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm();
```

Comment: You can edit your question so it is displayed nicely. If it helps, I can provide the full files/classes if you want. Example is from my school project.